# Notification On/Off after few seconds

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner with JavaScript and doing some exercise. When I add a new movie a notification is showing up after 0.5seconds, but I'm not sure afterward how can I set a time-interval of 2 seconds to hide the notification. Any help is appreciated!

```js
// Notification
function notify(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('notificationAddMovie').style.display = 'block'},500);
}
```

```css
/* Notification */
#notificationAddMovie{
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
    padding:1rem;
    bottom:10px;
    left:10px;
    background-color:#621940;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family: helvetica;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Movie Add Box-->
    <div id = 'notificationAddMovie'>
        <p>Successfully added!</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function notify(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('notificationAddMovie').style.display = 'block'
    }, 500);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('notificationAddMovie').style.display = 'none'
    }, 2000);
}
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: I have no clue, why it didn't workd when I tried that way. Thank you :)